# Android device for developing

Tags: android, device

I have recently started developing applications for mobile platforms. As of now, I have only been playing around with iOS but would also like to develop for Android and therefore I am going to a software development camp this summer which has its focus on Android development.

I have been offered a HTC Wildfire for a fair price and therefore I would like to hear if this phone is good for developing for Android or if there are any disadvantages or advantages? I am totally new to the Android platform and therefore I would like an advice on which devices I should look for and especially if the Wildfire can be used.

I hope you can help me :-)

Comment: See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/56025/mobile-development-obtaining-development-hardware-best-practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the two main factors when choosing device(s) for development/testing are the **screen density** and **Android OS version**.

The HTC Wildfire is typically thought of as a low-end device; the resolution is only 320x240 (lower than that of the very first Android phone, G1) and the rest of the specs aren't particularly impressive either. It has an LDPI (low density) screen and is currently upgradable to Android 2.2, from 2.1. For just starting out and learning Android development, the HTC Wildfire will do just fine.

Most newer phones are HDPI (high density) and will run Android [2.1, 2.2 or 2.3](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html). You should test with all screen densities using the emulator to make sure your application displays well on all of them. Use of the emulator reduces the need to test with multiple devices, but it is still better to use real devices if possible.

On one hand, if your app works great (performance-wise) with the Wildfire, then it will likely work great with everything else out there. Targeting the low-end means that your application will be able to potentially reach a wider audience.

On the other hand, testing with a more modern device will allow you to see how your application behaves on the current generation of devices, which may be more relevant to your interests.

Comment: Agree with the first paragraph but I'd add that you should check how badly the touchscreen sucks.  I didn't realise until I started to develop on my Desire that the multitouch is unfixably broken and that I should have held out for the HD.  Additionally, check it's powerful enough for you.  The Desire is more powerful than the Wildfire but the GPU is a bit weak compared to a lot of otherwise fairly similar phones.  Of course, if you like a challenge...

Comment: Okay. You both have some very good arguments that I did not think about. The Wildfire may be enough for me to start out but then again, it's a shame to spend money on a phone just to get a new one immediately after. I am more and more convinced that buying a HTC Desire will be a better.

Answer (score 0):

Any device that runs the Android OS is capable of being a testing device. The only differences can be the actual hardware in terms of response time, storage space, etc.

If you are using it to simply test applications that you are developing, then it certainly can be a useful device.

Comment: I was under the impression that some(or maybe even all) of the AT&T android devices were unable to check the 'Unknown Sources' option in the settings, and thus can't be used for development unless you flash an OS without this restriction.

Comment: I was unaware that different carriers had that restrictions on their phones. I am currently working with one from TELUS where this restriction is not in place.

Like you said though Tim, if the restriction is in place, then he simply needs to root the phone and then it's free reign for developing.

Comment: I don't know anything about rooting - but when reading about it, it does seem simple. Reading the other answers here, I am convinced that a Wildfire will do but might not be the smartest choice on the long run.

Answer (score 0):

An HTC wildfire will work as a development device. You may have to go out and find the ADB driver for it. Do keep in mind though, the more different devices you can test your applications on the more likely you are going to be to catch device specific problems and get them fixed before going live.

Comment: Find drivers for it? Oh, okay. You are right about different devices. Reading the other answers here, I am convinced that a Wildifre will do but a Desire might be a good choice. Then again, it's good to test on more devices. If I could get the Wildfire for a fair price, I might buy both. As written in an answer further down, it might be a good choice to test on both high- and low-end models.